# Getting a USB PD 3.0 port to output a constant voltage

Tags: usb-c

I am trying to use this [AC-DC wall adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PLR7T1M) as a simple constant voltage source to power a compact adjustable DC-DC converter.

www.amazon.com/Charger-RAVPower-Adapter-Compatible-MacBook/dp/B07PLR7T1M

I want the high power density that these new GaN transistor converters have, but the only ones I've found have only a USB-like output rather than a simple constant voltage that I want to power my DC-DC converter. Is there a way to make this AC adaptor output just a constant 20V?

I have tried to research how the PD 3.0 system decides what voltage and current limit to supply, but I have not understood an explanation for what I want since it is not what the USB PD system was designed for. I am thinking the solution would involve connecting certain value resistors to certain pins in the connector to signal the adaptor to output a constant voltage. Can any USB experts help me?

Comment: What wattage do you need? Why not use a regular AC-DC adapter, laptop style?

Comment: Because `I want the high power density that these new GaN transistor converters have` aka package size.

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate. Sorry I did not find that question in my original search. That PD trigger is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB C power delivery or quick charge technology is a bilateral communication protocol that is used to let a device request a specific voltage and current output. It is much more complicated than the older  standards which were just a signalling voltage or resistor voltage divider on the usb A data pins. In order to allow a typically 5V device to exist on the same port as a 20V device, a complicated protocol was deemed to be the best chance of not frying the low voltage device.

In order to use it as you want, a microcontroller typically is needed to either directly implement the handshake or a middleman dedicated USB PD ic is used. For a diy project, there are plenty of PD or QC ***trigger*** devices that will allow you to dumb down the communication to a simple jumper type selection. Look for these on the usual import friendly sites.

Comment: This is the solution for OP: https://www.ebay.com/itm/ZY12PDN-Type-C-PD-to-DC-USB-SurfacePro-Decoy-Fast-Charge-Trigger-Poller-/132745937609

Answer (score 1):

To get 20V out of a USB C power supply you need a USB power delivery controller designed to work with USB C (there was a version of USB power delivery for A/B connectors but afaict it never took off).

From some searching it seems the STUSB4500 should fill your requirements. It supports 20V mode and once the non-volatile memory is programmed it can work without support from a host processor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that chip.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a software configuration with Quick Charge 4 compliant protocol with 20 mV increments to 20V.

ref

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge

Perhaps you may prefer the more reliable Laptop charger supplies that provide 19.5V on a 3.5mm connector.

Comment: I have some AC-DC converters, but like I said I'm attracted to the higher power density of the one I linked.

Comment: It's very simple.  You cannot negotiate a 20V connection with a resistor value or any simple hardware connection. The load must have QC4 custom communication  to successfully demand this voltage link.  Were you looking for a DIY Hack?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a DIY hack.

Comment: That would require reverse engineering the analog design of your MacBook Charger to modify the regulator.

Comment: The charger selected by OP is not QC, but PD. It needs a different protocol over CC lines.

Comment: QC4 is compatible with both USB-PD and USB-C